# Could a living tube kite creature evolve/ exist?

Tags: evolution, aliens, anatomy, flight

On Deviantart I found a sketch of this creature:
[image]

It's called a "flying tube beetle" or more often a "flying lampshade". Think of it like a living tube kite that makes its own tether and catches what food it can while it floats in the wind. I don't know how big it's supposed to be. How could something like this evolve? Is this too far fetched?

Comment: "How could something like this evolve?" The same way all creatures evolve. Due to natural selection whereby environmental factors facilitate the adaptation of organisms. Anything can evolve, if it is viable, & natural selection cam do the shaping. This is how evolution works.

Comment: If it is viable *and* there is a viable path of incremental changes from some preexisting organism.

Comment: care to speculate a scenario for this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giant Pyrosomes are actually a real sea creature that is very similar to what you are describing, except it lives in the ocean and is a colony of organisms in stead of a single organism. It could get the information you are looking for.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosome

Comment: A good start, but let's all keep trying